# Google material icon shows wrong icon

Tags: css, web, google-material-icons

I have a file with just the following 4 lines:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<span style="outline:1px dotted green">
    <i class="material-icons">imagesmode</i>
</span>
```

The first line is just copied from [Material Icons Guide](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/material_icons).
The rest is how I usually inserts an icon.

The result looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

I expected just the first icon. (And with a little dot.) Am I doing something wrong?

---

EDIT: It seems to be a documentation problem in Material Icons Guide. Anyone knows where to report this specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace your icon to

```
<i class="material-icons">image</i>
```

You can find the code at [Google Fonts Icon](https://fonts.google.com/icons) by clicking the icon you need, and there will be a side bar popup. Scroll down to the "Inserting Icon" section and copy the code. In your case, you can just replace the icon name.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the problem here. You can find the icon I am using there too: https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.query=imagesmode

Comment: And inserting the code you suggest from "Inserting the icon" there just results in showing the word "image".

Comment: But your answer helped me. The documentation I linked to (Material Icons Guide) is simply wrong/outdated. (And I believe this has to do with the introduction of font faces/variables or whatever they call it.)